# Replacing text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, text, replace

After much trial an error and some progress I still can't mange to change every instance of `,-` with `kr` on my website.
I'm very much a beginner at JS and have pieced together the following code from several sources. Is the code the problem or something else?

```
function skrivkr() {
var skrivkr = $('div').text().replace(/\,-/g, 'kr');
$('p').html(skrivkr);
}
window.onload = skrivkr();
```

**Update:**
Thanks for the replies. The site loads jquery 1.10.7.
@Niet the Dark Absol: No, I don't want to put anything in p elements. How do I remove that part? I just want to find all `,-` and simply replace with kr without changing any formatting.

**Update**
OK! Progress, kind of. The ENTIRE content of every `<strong>` and `<dd>` now changes to (0), instead of kr. With the odd exception of those tags including ,-.  I haven't designed the site myself.

If it helps, one of the ,- appears in the following markup:

```
<a href="xxxx" rel="nofollow">
<span class="amount">1</span>
<span class="photo">
<img src="xxxx" alt="product name" width="62" height="42">
</span>
<span class="description">
Prtoduct name
<strong>4444,-</strong>
</span>
</a>
```

And the lastest script I'm applying is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('strong, dd').html($('strong, dd').html().replace(/,-/g, 'kr'));
});
```

Comment: your code works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k518rdLg/)

Comment: Sure this doesn't work? It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/wva2g8xe/

Comment: You're using jQuery. Did you include jQuery? You are taking the text content from all `<div>` elements and putting it in all `<p>` elements. Is this really what you want? Did you actually try understanding the code you copied?

Comment: This looks fine.  Can you post a sample of the text where it doesn't work?

Comment: if you to change the text on all the div, try running: $('div').text($(this).text().replace(/\-/g,'kr'));

Comment: Should be `window.onload = skrivkr;` (no parens). Also, I cannot really recommend using the same identifier for the function and an identifier within in, although it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the content of each div like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').each(function(){
        var newText = $(this).html().replace(/,-/g, 'kr');
        $(this).html(newText);
    });
});
```

You can remove the var "newText = " and replace it with $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/,-/g, 'kr'));
The first example is easier to understand perhaps if you are new to programming.
You will, however only change the content of text placed in  tags.

I would place the text to replace in a div with some predefine class, like "autoKronor", it would then look like this:

```
<div class="autoKronor">123,-</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.autoKronor').each(function(){
        var newText = $(this).html().replace(/,-/g, 'kr');
        $(this).html(newText);
    });
});
```

to en sure that only text you intended to change gets changed..
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/akm1uw8h/2/

Also note the use of $(document).ready(); instead of window.onload. It does what you intended to do with window.onload.

if you really want to change EVERY single instance of ",-" to "kr" then you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').html($('body').html().replace(/,-/g, 'kr'));
});
```

**But i strongly advice against the last example because it will be the slowest to compute and more importantly you might change stuff you don't intend to, like any script block inside the page body (with that i mean other javascripts)**

Comment: I tried the first version of the code and the result is that all site structure and formatting on the site disappears and I get a huge text block. Plus, the script itself appears in plaintext.

Comment: Try with the new version

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. The site keeps loading but not showing anything. The ,- on the site appears in `<strong>` and `<dd>` tags. would it be wise to specify by using $('strong;dd').html($(strong;dd').html()... ?

Comment: You will have to use $('strong, dd') as your selector, not just $(strong;dd') (probably just a typo, but it still matters). Have you designed the site yourself? Is it possible for you to change or add "css"-classes on tags? If you can, then using classes to designate where you want it to change the text would be the best, because then you can decide where it should change the text (and you don't need to worry about as many "what if" scenarios)

Comment: And yes, you CAN use whatever tag you want, but the more specific you are the better. That is why i would use classes to define where to swap the ,- for kr

Comment: For me your current code works, i have made a demo here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lkfnh2hv/ .I am sure we have asked you about this, but you are 100% sure you are loading jquery on your site, right? Can you also confirm that the link i posted in this comment works for you? The output should be something like "1 (broken image link) Product name 4444kr"

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned innumerable times here on SO, do not try to manipulate the DOM as a string. Pain awaits.

Instead, traverse the DOM, finding text nodes, and perform whatever transformation you want to make on each text node. There are many ways to do that.

In your case, you have many problems, as mentioned already by some of the commenters and responders:

1. You're setting `window.onload` to `undefined` (the result of **calling** `skrivkr`), instead of to `skrivkr` itself.
2. You're extracting the text value of an element, which consists of the concatenation of all text down all levels, performing the replacement, then sticking it back in with `html`. This will wipe out all the element structure below.
3. Minor point, but there's no need to escape the comma in the regexp.
4. You're extracting the textual content of all `div` elements in the entire document, transforming it, then adding that back as the content of all `p` elements in the entire document. It's hard to imagine that's what you want to do.

Comment: Thans for the feedback. I see now the code was more faulty than I thought.